# How can I set [NotNull, Default(value: 0)] for a class used to create a SQLITE table in Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set a default value in a class that's used to define a table in SQLITE like this:

```
using System;
using SQLite;

namespace Japanese {

public class Phrase
{

    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public string PhraseId { get; set; }
    public int PhraseNum { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public bool Selected { get; set; } 
    [NotNull, Default(value: 0)]
    public bool Viewed   { get; set; }
}
}
```

I'm getting an error saying:

> /Phrase.cs(19,19): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'DefaultAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: try including `using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` in your code.

Comment: Which version of SQLite.Net-PCL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bool` always initialize to false, as you are setting 0 for `Viewed` which means false in SQLite. However if you need some other fields to be initialized you can do it through property itself, field default value not going change until another value going to set.

```
private bool _sel = true;
[NotNull]
public bool Selected
{
    get { return _sel; }
    set { _sel = value; }
}
```

Probably you want `PhraseId` `AutoIncreament` instead of `NotNull` because `PrimarKey` always `NotNull` constraint in it.

Comment: AutoIncreament on the primary key won't work since it's defined as a string. It should just be initialized in the constructor to a guid/uuid.